# Conditional Poisson Process- Time of nth Event

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes

Let $N(t), t\geq 0$ be a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda = 2$. Let $S_{n}$ denote the time of the $n^{th}$ event. Find $E(S_{6}|N(2)=4)$.

I have been told that $E(S_{6}|N(2)=4) = 2 + E(S_{6}-S_{4}) = 2+ E(S_{6}) -E(S_{4})$.

How is it that $E(S_{6}|N(2)=4) = 2 + E(S_{6}-S_{4})$?

How do we know that $2 + E(S_{6}-S_{4}) = 2+ E(S_{6}) -E(S_{4})$, given that we have not been told if the $S_{n}$ are independent?.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your second question, $E[X-Y] = E[X] - E[Y]$ always holds, even if $X$ and $Y$ are dependent.

I think the first step is not correct (although it leads you to the right answer).

Here is how I would think of it.
Conditioned on $N(2) = 4$, you can think of the Poisson process starting anew at time $2$ (independent increments property). So the sixth event in the full process is actually the second event after time $2$, and thus $E[S_6 \mid N(2) = 4] = 2 + E[S_6 - 2 \mid N(2) = 4] = 2 + E[\tilde{S}_2] = 2 + 2 / \lambda$, where I am using $\tilde{S}_2$ to denote the time of the second event in a separate Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$.

Comment: How does $N(2)=4$ affect the result in $E(S_{6}-2|N(2)=4)$? Also, why is $E(\tilde{S_{2}}) = \frac{2}{\lambda}?$

Comment: If you know that $N(2)=4$, then everything after time $2$ is like a new Poisson process with the same intensity. So the sixth event would be the second event after time $2$. One can show that the expected time until the second event in a Poisson process is $2 / \lambda$ (because the expected time between consecutive events is $1/\lambda$).